# Which files needed to deploy PostgreSQL app created using Delphi?

Tags: postgresql, delphi, deployment, firemonkey

I had developed a Delphi PostgreSQL database application that run on Windows/ Ubuntu and MacOS using FireDAC components, i want to know Which files needed to deploy a Delphi application on Windows 7 and what are the files needed to deploy to Ubuntu and MacOS?

Comment: [Connect to PostgreSQL (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Connect_to_PostgreSQL_(FireDAC))

Comment: Your first stop should always be the documentation, before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [PgDAC](https://www.devart.com/pgdac/) (or [UniDAC](https://www.devart.com/unidac/), if you also need to connect to databases differ than PostgreSQL). In this case, nothing should be deployed except the application for Windows, Ubuntu and MacOS.